# Issues loading IronRuby.Rack assembly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ironruby, rack

I'm trying to get IronRuby on Rails running with iis7 server 2k8 and can only get as far as it cannot load the assembly 'IronRuby.Rack' (Screen Shot: http://grab.by/3VZm)  has anyone gotten this working?  Any tips you can give me?

Thanks,
-CJ

Answer (score 2):

A full tutorial of how to get this working is located at http://www.iamnotmyself.com/2010/04/22/RunningRailsInIIS7WithIronRubyRack.aspx